# Template deducing wrong type?

Tags: templates, visual-c++, c++17

Could someone please explain to me why Visual Studio thinks that this unordered_set has a `hash<ItemUID>` template parameter rather than a `hash<ChunkHash>` parameter?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't understand templates very well, and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. As far as I'm aware, creating multiple typedefs for the same type is perfectly valid C++, no? How do I convince the set that its key is a `ChunkHash`, not an `ItemUID`?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, apparently [std::unordered_set.contains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/contains) is a C++20 feature...